# Hard cubic equation

Tags: systems-of-equations, cubics

If $$x=a+b+c;y=-(ab+bc+ac); z=-abc$$
solve the following equation:
$$t^3-xt^2-yt+z=0$$
I was thinking to use the identity
$$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=\frac{1}{2}[(a-b)^2+(b-c)^2+(a-c)^2]$$
but I don't know how.
Maybe it's not useful but $x$, $y$ and $z$ are solutions of the following system
$$a^2x+ay-z=a^3$$
$$b^2x+by-z=a^3$$
$$c^2x+cy-z=c^3$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since\begin{align}(t-a)(t-b)(t-c)&=t^3-a t^2-b t^2-c t^2+a b t+a c t+b c t-a b c\\&=t^3-xt^2-yt+z,\end{align}the roots are $a$, $b$, and $c$.

Comment: Very nice, but how can one consider the term (t−a)(t−b)(t−c) ? How did you know to choose it?

Comment: With experience, @Andrei, you would recognize the symmetric functions of which the coefficients consist.

Comment: It's the only way to do it with high school methods? Just figuring out that product?

Comment: Yes, I suppose so.

Comment: Do you think that I have answered your question?

Comment: Yes. Thank you for your time.